# user-scalable affect sticky footer (on mobile only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm dealing with a very strange problem.
When the page is in mobile view the sticky footer get stuck at the bottom of the page unless I add the value user-scalable attribute to the viewport meta tag.
Is there a way to make it work without adding this attribute to the meta tag?
Thanks!!!

[Here is my code example](https://jsfiddle.net/q7Lzy1oj/1/)

```
    <style type="text/css">

            body {
                background:#FFFFBF;
                color:#2D1F16;
                font:13px Helvetica,  Arial,  sans-serif
            }

            .wrap {
                position:relative;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:900px;
            }

            #header, #footer {
                width:100%;
                float:left;
                padding:15px 0;
            }

            #header {
                background:#DBFA56;
                clear:both;
                height:100px;
                left:0;
            }

            #header .logo {
                float:left;
                width:400px;
                font-size:24px;
            }

            #header p {
                float:right;
                width:400px;
                margin:0;
            }

            #content {
                padding:15px 0;
                margin-top:120px;
                float:left;
            }

            #footer {
                background: #0289ce;
                text-align:center;
                position:fixed;
                bottom:0;
                z-index:999999;
            }

            #footer a {
                color:#fff;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">Logo Of Your Site!</a>
            </div>
            <p>This site is amazing!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>This is an example of centered body content!</h1>
            <p>'May it please your Majesty,' said Two, in a very humble tone, going down on one knee as he spoke, 'we were trying&mdash;'</p>
            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
                three of the soldiers remaining behind to execute the unfortunate gardeners, who ran to Alice for protection.</p>
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>
            <p>'May it please your Majesty,' said Two, in a very humble tone, going down on one knee as he spoke, 'we were trying&mdash;'</p>
            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
                three of the soldiers remaining behind to execute the unfortunate gardeners, who ran to Alice for protection.</p>
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>
            <p>'May it please your Majesty,' said Two, in a very humble tone, going down on one knee as he spoke, 'we were trying&mdash;'</p>
            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
                three of the soldiers remaining behind to execute the unfortunate gardeners, who ran to Alice for protection.</p>
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>
            <p>'May it please your Majesty,' said Two, in a very humble tone, going down on one knee as he spoke, 'we were trying&mdash;'</p>
            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>
            <p>'May it please your Majesty,' said Two, in a very humble tone, going down on one knee as he spoke, 'we were trying&mdash;'</p>
            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
                three of the soldiers remaining behind to execute the unfortunate gardeners, who ran to Alice for protection.</p>
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>


            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
                three of the soldiers remaining behind to execute the unfortunate gardeners, who ran to Alice for protection.</p>
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>
            <p>'May it please your Majesty,' said Two, in a very humble tone, going down on one knee as he spoke, 'we were trying&mdash;'</p>
            <p>'I see!' said the Queen, who had meanwhile been examining the roses. 'Off with their heads!' and the procession moved on,
                three of the soldiers remaining behind to execute the unfortunate gardeners, who ran to Alice for protection.</p>
            <p>'You shan't be beheaded!' said Alice, and she put them into a large flower-pot that stood near. The three soldiers wandered
                about for a minute or two, looking for them, and then quietly marched off after the others.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="wrap">
            <p>This is an Ad
                Aviad is the Best
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `the sticky footer get stuck at the bottom of the page` - isn't the sticky footer suppose to get stuck at the bottom? or am I missing something?

Comment: @OfirBaruch its should be at the bottom and follow the user's scrolling, take a look in my jsfiddle code.